# Sidekiq Web behind AWS Load Balancer

Tags: sidekiq

We are facing an issue mounting Sidekiq Web behind AWS Load Balancer, we got Forbiden when perform any action. The web UI is rendered without any problem.

The sidekiq is running in Fargate and requests go through AWS Load Balancer. Anyone has faced something similar?

**EDIT**

It's not rails App.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like your application might need to configure the `Rack::Session::Cookie` middleware properly.  For example place this in your `config.ru`, and set the `RACK_SECRET` environment variable to **the same value on all hosts**.

```rb
# set up a Session middleware
use Rack::Session::Cookie, secret: ENV['RACK_SECRET'], same_site: true, max_age: 86400

# run the Sidekiq web app
run Sidekiq::Web
```

Comment: I will test these options `same_site: true, max_age: 86400` because my `config.ru` has a valid session config using Rack::Session::Cookie middleware.